# how to get the desire rows by condition in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the DataFrame with index is the post_code and its value as medicines name and proportion. How can I just get 1 medicine name for each post_code alphabetically (some post_codes may have multiple 'bnf_name' with the same rate for the maximum. In this case, take the alphabetically first 'bnf_name')

```
  post_code        bnf                        dev
  TR1 3ER  Senna_Tab 7.5mg                   0.33
  TR1 3ER  Oxybutynin HCl_Tab 2.5mg          0.33
  B26 1TH  Betnesol_Ear/Eye/Nose Dps 0.1%    0.16
  B26 1TH  Amoxicillin_Cap 500mg             0.16
```

Desired result:

```
   post_code        bnf                            dev
  TR1 3ER     Oxybutynin HCl_Tab 2.5mg             0.33
  B26 1TH     Amoxicillin_Cap 500mg                0.16
```

Comment: What about you have multiple `bnf` for the same `post_code` but with different `dev`values?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably first want to [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by *both* index `post_code` and column `bnf` and then use [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) while keeping the first occurrence:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['post_code', 'bnf'])
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['post_code'], keep='first')
```

Comment: Thanks, however it is not sort and keep the max 'dev' value for each 'post_code'

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. My answer does not sort by ‘dev’, but first by ‘post_code’ and second by ‘bnf’. The ‘dev’ value is ignored. Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Did you run the code? Wrong result?

Comment: I have just changed your code a little bit and get the result. Thank you so much!

Comment: What did you change? So that I can correct the answer.

Comment: just change the 'bnf' to 'dev' and set the ascending to False

Comment: OK. You don't mention `dev` or sorting by `dev` in your question at all. I assume that's what I have been missing. Could you please edit your question so that `dev` is defined? Other things not properly defined in your question are `rate` and `proportion` (I suspect one of them is `dev`). Thanks.